# How to measure +-10V signal with the ADS1115

Tags: adc

Recently i have done a measurement of an +-20mA source.
I used a shunt resistor of 10ohm and read the voltage (in differential mode) at the pins A2 and A3 of the ADS1115.
This part is working propely (no damages).

Second goal was to measure +-10V, but i was damaging the ADC when i wired it like the screenshot below.
What was the fault?

I used a voltage devider, to ensure to not exceed the limit of the 5V power supply of the ADC.

Here is a screenshot of my wiring:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the voltage of A1 with respect to GND of ADS1115? It seems like the inputs and ADC dont share the same ground. It might be possible that ground of 10V circuit on the left is way higher or lower than the GND of the ADC. It mostly seems like the A1 which is connected to negative side of the battery is at way lower voltage when compared to GND. Similar situation could have occured with current source as well but the voltage developed is just 20m*10 = 200mV which is very less to cause any damage.

Answer (score 0):

Although the measurement is differential between A0 and A1, if one of them is higher than VDD+0.3, the board will get damaged. You should measure the "negative pole" voltage of the 10V source. For example, if VDD is 5 V and negative pole is 4 V in relation to GND, then A0 or A1 (the highest) will be 6V for the ADS1115. If possible, I'd suggest you to connect the one of the poles of the source to GND